Custom sort order according to cell value
Currently I sort my sheet via this function
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(a);
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
dataRange.sort([
  {column: role, ascending: true},
  {column: cases, ascending: false}
]);

This sorts the by role first in alphabetical order. Is it possible to customise this sort ?
For example, ideally the sort is by role level and not aplhabetical
Eg. if the roles are [intern, junior, senior, lead, manager] can the sheet be sorted in that order ?

Why not add a column that translates these roles to a sequence number you can then sort by?

The data is peridodically imported and I have no access to modify the source. I was hoping to do this without changing columns as it will impact other functions.

Here is my sample data.  My table doesn't show it but column a is a drop down selection




A
B
C
D
E




1
COL1
COL2
COL3
COL4
COL5


2
intern
B2
C2
D2
E2


3
junior
B3
C3
D3
E3


4
senior
B4
C4
D4
E4


5
lead
B5
C5
D5
E5


6
manager
B6
C6
D6
E6


7
intern
B7
C7
D7
E7


8
junior
B8
C8
D8
E8


9
senior
B9
C9
D9
E9


10
lead
B10
C10
D10
E10


11
manager
B11
C11
D11
E11


12
intern
B12
C12
D12
E12


13
junior
B13
C13
D13
E13


14
senior
B14
C14
D14
E14


15
lead
B15
C15
D15
E15


16
manager
B16
C16
D16
E16


17
intern
B17
C17
D17
E17


18
junior
B18
C18
D18
E18


19
senior
B19
C19
D19
E19


20
lead
B20
C20
D20
E20


21
manager
B21
C21
D21
E21


22
intern
B22
C22
D22
E22


23
junior
B23
C23
D23
E23


24
senior
B24
C24
D24
E24


25
lead
B25
C25
D25
E25


26
manager
B26
C26
D26
E26



My Script:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var rg = sh.getRange(2,1,sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn());
  var vs = rg.getValues();
  var list = ['intern', 'junior', 'senior', 'lead', 'manager'];
  vs.sort((a,b) =>{
    return list.indexOf(a[0]) - list.indexOf(b[0]);//switch a and b to sort descending
  } )
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs).replace(/],/g,'],\n'))
  //rg.setValues(vs);
}

Here's the logger output:
[["intern","B2","C2","D2","E2"],
["intern","B7","C7","D7","E7"],
["intern","B12","C12","D12","E12"],
["intern","B17","C17","D17","E17"],
["intern","B22","C22","D22","E22"],
["junior","B3","C3","D3","E3"],
["junior","B8","C8","D8","E8"],
["junior","B13","C13","D13","E13"],
["junior","B18","C18","D18","E18"],
["junior","B23","C23","D23","E23"],
["senior","B4","C4","D4","E4"],
["senior","B9","C9","D9","E9"],
["senior","B14","C14","D14","E14"],
["senior","B19","C19","D19","E19"],
["senior","B24","C24","D24","E24"],
["lead","B5","C5","D5","E5"],
["lead","B10","C10","D10","E10"],
["lead","B15","C15","D15","E15"],
["lead","B20","C20","D20","E20"],
["lead","B25","C25","D25","E25"],
["manager","B6","C6","D6","E6"],
["manager","B11","C11","D11","E11"],
["manager","B16","C16","D16","E16"],
["manager","B21","C21","D21","E21"],
["manager","B26","C26","D26","E26"]]

Just learn how to use the Javascript Array.sort() with the compare function. Use your favorite javascript reference.
Regarding your question about sorting multiple columns here is a snippet of a sorting routine that sorts bible verses in biblical canonical order.  As you can  see it begins to get a little more complicated. But the idea is still the same.
vs.sort((a, b) => {
    let tA = [a[1], a[2]];
    let tB = [b[1], b[2]];
    let ia = vers.indexOf(a[3].toString());
    let ib = vers.indexOf(b[3].toString());
    if (~ia && ~ib) {
      let vA = (vers.indexOf(a[3]) * 1000);
      vA += (a[3] == b[3]) ? (booknames.indexOf(a[0]) * 100) : 0;
      vA += (a[0] == b[0]) ? (Number(tA[0]) * 10) : 0;
      vA += (tA[0] == tB[0]) ? (Number(tA[1]) * 1) : 0;
      let vB = (vers.indexOf(b[3]) * 1000)
      vB += (a[3] == b[3]) ? (booknames.indexOf(b[0]) * 100) : 0;
      vB += (a[0] == b[0]) ? (Number(tB[0]) * 10) : 0;
      vB += tA[0] == tB[0] ? (Number(tB[1]) * 1) : 0;
      Logger.log("vA: %s vB: %s VersionA: %s versionB: %s NameA: %s NameB: %s verseA: %s:%s verseB: %s:%s", vA, vB, a[3], b[3], a[0], b[0], tA[0], tA[1], tB[0], tB[1])
      return vA - vB;
    }
  })


This works great! Thank you ... would it be possible to sort on Col1(the roles) and Col2 ?

Yes but it get's a little more complicated because sorting on a secondary column requires that you only sort when the two rows in the previous column are equal so that you are sorting only in the proper sub domain.  I left a portion of a snippect that sorts bible verses in biblical canonical order as an example.

Sorts the role level using ForEach
By sorting the level from intern to manager, all of the data from your dataRange will be retrieved, and the setValues will be returned to the designated range.
Sample Table:









intern
a


junior
b


manager
c


lead
d


senior
e


intern
f


junior
g


manager
h


lead
i


senior
j



Output Table:









intern
a


intern
f


junior
b


junior
g


senior
e


senior
j


lead
d


lead
i


manager
c


manager
h



Script:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("a");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var output = []
  var hier = ['intern', 'junior', 'senior', 'lead', 'manager'];
  hier.forEach(x => {
    var temp = [];
    data.forEach(y => (y[0] == x) ? temp.push(y) : null);
    temp.sort().forEach(z => output.push(z))
  });
  dataRange.setValues(output);
}


This script is Anti pattern in the long run it is hard to maintain and may result from recurring problems.

UPDATE using Sort Method
Using sort() to identify the hierarchy of the heir order and localeCompare() method compares two strings in the current locale and to sort the second column alphabetically.
Another Script:
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("a");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  var hier = { intern: 1, junior: 2, senior: 3, lead: 4, manager: 5 }

  data.sort((a, b) => {
    var roleA = a[0];
    var roleB = b[0];
    var arrange = (hier[roleA]) - (hier[roleB]);
    
    if (arrange === 0) return a[1].localeCompare();

    return arrange;
  });

  dataRange.setValues(data);
}

Reference:

forEach

Ternary

localeCompare



Using forEach for sort is an antipattern.

@TheMaster thank you for the insights, I added another script using the sort method.

You can use a Map object to assign a numerical value to each role and sort based on those values. Hopefully this works as intended.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(a);
var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
var data = dataRange.getValues();

var roleOrder = {
  'intern': 1,
  'junior': 2,
  'senior': 3,
  'lead': 4,
  'manager': 5
};

data.sort(function(row1, row2) {
  var role1 = row1[role - 1]; 
  var role2 = row2[role - 1];
  
  if (roleOrder[role1] < roleOrder[role2]) {
    return -1;
  } else if (roleOrder[role1] > roleOrder[role2]) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return row2[cases - 1] - row1[cases - 1];
  }
});

sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);


strange code. why role - 1? and where is the map?

@NinaScholz Isn't roleOrder a map? Also role - 1 to prevent zero-indexing.

While an object can be used as hashmap, when you say Map object, it means https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map
